# How to use supervisor start/stop uwsgi(4 processes)

Tags: uwsgi, supervisord

This is my centos uwsgi service setting:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI for uwsgi
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Restart=always
ExecStart=/usr/share/nginx/ENV/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/nginx/ENV/config/uwsgi.ini
StandardError=syslog
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/uwsgi.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I want to convert to use supervisor to start/stop the uwsgi service
But still not find a solution
Please help me

This is my supervisor.conf :

```
[program:wiarea-positioning]
command = /usr/share/nginx/ENV/bin/uwsgi --ini /usr/share/nginx/ENV/config/uwsgi.ini
stdout_logfile=/var/log/uwsgi.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/uwsgi.log
;stopasgroup = true
stopsignal=QUIT
```

This is my uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /usr/share/nginx/ENV/mysite

env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings
module = mysite.wsgi:application
# the virtualenv  
home = /usr/share/nginx/ENV
master = true
thunder-lock=true
processes = 4
pidfile =  /var/run/uwsgi.pid
socket = 127.0.0.1:8001
daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi.log
vacuum = true
```

Comment: Why do you want to move it to supervisor?

Comment: Because I want to retry if it start fail

Comment: Consider using [uWSGI emperor](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Emperor.html). It is much better to manage than supervisor services and it have some uwsgi-specified management tools, like passing variables to all vassals, passing socket file for comunication, throttling, loyality system, heartbeat etc. It will probably fit your needs better.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem (at least one of them) is this uwsgi.ini line:

`daemonize = /var/log/uwsgi.log`

Remember that supervisor basically just runs your `command=` command from the command line, and waits for it to exit. If it exits, supervisor runs the command again.

The uwsgi `daemonize` option breaks this, because it causes the main uwsgi command to start a background process and immediately exit. Supervisor doesn't know about the background process, so it assumes the command failed and tries to restart it repeatedly. You can confirm this is what's happening by looking at the log files in the `/var/log/supervisor/` folder.

So, if you want to run uwsgi with supervisor, you need to remove the daemonize option. After that, you can try just running the command from the command line to confirm that uwsgi starts and stays in the foreground.

[This blog](https://bixly.com/blog/supervisord-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-um-use-supervisord) has more discussion of daemon processes and supervisor: